# CakePHP - saveAssociated/saveAll behaves like saveMany

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two Models, namely Product and ProductSpecification which have the following relations in place:

```
(Product Model)
public $hasMany = array(
    'ProductSpecification' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductSpecification',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
```

and

```
(ProductSpecification Model)
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    )
);
```

Using the CakePHP Form helper I post ProductSpecification data and then I use the `saveAll` method (or `saveAssociated`, I've tried both) to save the data. `debug($this->request->data)` gives me the following output after POSTing:

```
array(
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '2'
    ),
    'ProductSpecification' => array(
        'title' => 'test',
        'step' => '1',
        'position' => '1'
    )
)
```

This is great, right..? Now, the line after the debug I use the following code to save (I've also tried saveAssociated):

```
if($this->Product->saveAll($this->request->data))
```

For some odd reason this saves three(!) empty rows in my ProductSpecification table, with only the `product_id` field (and `id`) set; the fields `title`, `step` and `position` are empty. Exactly the same behavior happens when I run `saveAssociated`. What am I doing wrong?

I'm running CakePHP 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your save data should look more like this:-

```
array(
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '2'
    ),
    'ProductSpecification' => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'test',
            'step' => '1',
            'position' => '1'
        )
    )
);
```

The values for `ProductSpecification` need to be passed as a numerically indexed array for the `hasMany` relationship.

Also, make sure you use `saveAssociated()` rather than `saveAll()` as you are passing associated data so there is no need to use the wrapper method (which should be avoided wherever possible).

Comment: Oh man, you're totally right. I assumed it also worked for `hasMany` relations, as long as you'd call the `saveAssociated` function.

Comment: What you had would be correct for a `belongsTo` association. `saveAssociated()` checks the model association to determine the expected data structure for saving, so expects an array of `ProductSpecification` records in your case. `saveAll()` is just a wrapper method, so will still call `saveAssociated()`. As you should really know what sort of data you are planning on saving I'd always recommend steering clear of `saveAll()` as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware `saveAssociated` checked the model association to determine it, I expected it to check for numeric indexes or not. Thanks! I actually replaced the `saveAssociated` for a `saveAll` to see whether or not that worked, as I always use either the `saveAssociated` or `saveMany` depending on the situation. Only just found out it only functioned as a wrapper for the two.